# SharePoint CSOM adding invalid records

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am writing some scripting processes in C# to update a SharePoint Online list with data from a system database (there's a whole heap in between, but that's irrelevant).

The issue I am having is that when I add new records, they are being added without validation rules being applied by SharePoint e.g. you can add an entry that has a missing mandatory field which then shows up OnLine with a `(!) Required` placeholder.

In the example below, lets assume the list has these (text) fields all of which are tagged as mandatory.

```
Title
Address
Rating (Just a simple 3 letter code)
```

And then the script has the following to add a new item ..

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("my sponline site url");
List myList = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("my list");

ListItemCreationInformation newRecContext = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem newItem = myList.AddItem(newRecContext);

newRecord.Add("Title", "My Name"); 
newRecord.Add("Address", "My Address");

/* Removed for Testing validation*/
//newRecord.Add("Rating", "AAA"); 

newItem.Update();

clientContext.Load(newItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If the "Rating" field is populated then all good, item gets added... but if the line is removed should it not raise an exception to say that a mandatory field (Rating) is not provided.

Why is the CSOM not checking for validity?

Edit: I am using the Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM (v16.1.7115.1200) package from NuGet

Answer (score 1):

None of the code object models apply those rules.  They're strictly for the UI controls shown to users.  This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how Sharepoint works. If you add list items programmatically - by default it does not validate required fields. You should just keep it in mind (on other hand - you have more freedom). You can add your custom validation in place where you save item. Other way is to create list item event receiver for your list and add your validation in the ItemUpdating method.